# How do I compile the asm generated by GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, assembly

I'm playing around with some asm code, and something is bothering me.

I compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

with `gcc file.c -S -o file.S` this generates a nice little piece of asm code:

```
    .cstring
LC0:
    .ascii "Hello World\0"
    .text
.globl _main
_main:
LFB3:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
    subq    $16, %rsp
LCFI2:
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    leaq    LC0(%rip), %rdi
    call    _puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
LFE3:
    .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
EH_frame1:
    .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
    .long L$set$0
LSCIE1:
    .long   0x0
    .byte   0x1
    .ascii "zR\0"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x78
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x7
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x90
    .byte   0x1
    .align 3
LECIE1:
.globl _main.eh
_main.eh:
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .quad   LFB3-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE3-LFB3
    .quad L$set$2
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB3
    .long L$set$3
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x86
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
    .long L$set$4
    .byte   0xd
    .byte   0x6
    .align 3
LEFDE1:
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

My next problem is really, how do I compile this output, and can I make GCC do it for me?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Yes, You can use gcc to compile your asm code. Use -c for compilation like this:

```
gcc -c file.S -o file.o
```

This will give object code file named file.o. 
To invoke linker perform following after above command:

```
gcc file.o -o file
```

Comment: you can also just use `gcc file.S -o file`

Comment: what about "> as -o hello.o hello.s" ? as indicated by https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html. Seems like the order of process is preprocessing (*.i-file), compiling(*.s-file), assembling(*.o-file) and linking (*.exe-file).

Comment: @user1677716: Yes, that's what `gcc -c` runs if you give it a `.s` file.  You can use `gcc -v` to see the commands it runs, e.g. `gcc -v  -c foo.s` or `gcc -v foo.s` to assemble *and link*.  The linking part is more complex than just `ld foo.o`; it has to link with CRT startup code, and libraries including libc (`-lc`).

Answer (score 60):

`gcc` can use an assembly file as input, and invoke the assembler as needed. There is a subtlety, though:

- If the file name ends with "`.s`" (lowercase 's'), then `gcc` calls the assembler.
- If the file name ends with "`.S`" (uppercase 'S'), then `gcc` applies the C preprocessor on the source file (i.e. it recognizes directives such as `#if` and replaces macros), and *then* calls the assembler on the result.

So, on a general basis, you want to do things like this:

```
gcc -S file.c -o file.s
gcc -c file.s
```

Comment: This looks like its working but I get an error message: 'Malformed Mach-o file'

Comment: I think you have to use the `.S` prefix (uppercase) otherwise gcc detects another filetype (failed with `.asm` for instance)

Answer (score 13):

You can embed the assembly code in a normal C program. Here's a good [introduction](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html). Using the appropriate syntax, you can also tell GCC you want to interact with variables declared in C. The program below instructs gcc that:

- eax shall be foo
- ebx shall be bar
- the value in eax shall be stored in foo after the assembly code executed

\n

```
int main(void)
{
        int foo = 10, bar = 15;
        __asm__ __volatile__("addl  %%ebx,%%eax"
                             :"=a"(foo)
                             :"a"(foo), "b"(bar)
                             );
        printf("foo+bar=%d\n", foo);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, gcc can also compile assembly source code. Alternatively, you can invoke `as`, which is the assembler. (gcc is just a "driver" program that uses heuristics to call C compiler, C++ compiler, assembler, linker, etc..)

Comment: How do I figure out how gcc would have used as ?

Comment: Also, I have Intels icc lying arround, what assembler do they use?

Comment: @Martin, ask `gcc -v` to narrate its actions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GAS, which is gcc's backend assembler:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/as

Answer (score 3):

If you have main.s file.
you can generate object file by `GCC` and also `as`

```
# gcc -c main.s
# as main.s -o main.o
```

check this link, it will help you learn some binutils of GCC
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/01/gnu-binutils-commands/

Comment: Note that you can't *link* into an executable with `ld` (without adding a bunch of options): You still want `gcc main.o -o main` to link with CRT start code and `-lc`

Answer (score -3):

```
nasm -f bin -o 2_hello 2_hello.asm
```

Comment: This is quite a short answer. Could you add some explanation, please? Maybe you can tell us what the parameters do and what you do differently compared to the other answers.

Comment: GCC doesn't generate NASM syntax, it generates GAS with AT&T or `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  There is no combination of GCC and NASM options that will let you compile C to asm with GCC and then assemble it with NASM.